# Is my hard disk faulty/dying?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, hibernate, hd-tune

This question was motivated by my issue where coming back from hibernate takes a long time. i.e even after the OS loads up etc, there is a lot of disk activity and the PC is generally laggy and slow for a while (like 5-10 min!). I have a greedy firefox and a Lubuntu VM running at most times, so RAM usage is quite high.

However when i see Task manager, [as attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4e2gn.png), the bandwidth on the disk is only 2-5 MBps. I ran HD Tune, the first time around it created a spikey but low graph, but my laptop froze before i could capture it (possibly caused by it). However once i rebooted the machine, it seemed to work much better, and HDtune was able to get high double digits of MBps out of it (task manager agreed with this as well, showing about 70MBps).

What does this mean? Is this a disk that is dying? Or is this something related to hibernation? This is a laptop with a HDD, probably one of the 5200 RPM ones, and on SATA II

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive’s SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: Is your disk LED blinking furiously during those 5-10 minutes?